# C# Winform- Combobox2 Changes when combobox1 change using Foreign key Sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes in my Winforms application, one is for Table 1 one

`Curricuculum` table

```
CurriculumID (PK, auto-increment)
CurriculumName Varchar(255)
```

`GradeLevel` table

```
GradeLevelID (PK, auto-increment)
GradeLevel Varchar(255)
CurriculumID (foreign key)
```

Example for the data:

Curricuculum table

```
CurriculumID   CurriculumName
-------------- ----------
1              Grade Levels
2              Kinder Levels
3              College Levels
```

GradeLevel table

```
GradeLevelID   CurriculumID   GradeLevelName
 -------       -------------- ----------
 1             1              Grade 1
 2             1              Grade 2
 3             1              Grade 3
 4             2              Kinder 1
 5             2              Kinder 2
 6             3              College 1
 7             3              College 2
 8             3              College 3
```

i want Select Grade Levels in Combobox 1, then Grade 1, Grade 2, Grade 3 will show up in Combobox 2.

Problem:
the code i used so far Shows all the Columns in Grade Level(Combobox 2) whenever i select anything from Combobox1

This is my code so far

```
public schedulingForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CCombobox();
            GLCombobox();
        }



private void CCombobox()
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            int i = 0;
            string sql = null;
            connetionString = "Data Source=.\\KENNETH;Initial Catalog=HSPAEnrollmentSytem;Integrated Security=True";
            sql = "select CurriculumID,CurriculumName from Curriculum";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                adapter.Dispose();
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
                this.cbCurriculum.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                this.cbCurriculum.ValueMember = "CurriculumID";
                this.cbCurriculum.DisplayMember = "CurriculumName";
                this.cbCurriculum.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
                this.comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "CurriculumID";
                this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CurriculumID";
                this.comboBox1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection!");
            }
        }






private void GLCombobox()
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int i = 0;
        string sql = null;
        connetionString = "Data Source=.\\KENNETH;Initial Catalog=HSPAEnrollmentSytem;Integrated Security=True";
        sql = "select GradeLevelID,GradeLevel from GradeLevel";
        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            adapter.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
            this.cbGradeLevel.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            this.cbGradeLevel.ValueMember = "GradeLevelID";
            this.cbGradeLevel.DisplayMember = "GradeLevel";
            this.cbGradeLevel.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
            this.comboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            this.comboBox2.ValueMember = "GradeLevelID";
            this.comboBox2.DisplayMember = "GradeLevelID";
            this.comboBox2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection!");
        }
    }

private void cbCurriculum_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GLCombobox();

    }
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question. In fact we don't know what problems you have or what is the specific question. With what we have: You can subscribe the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `Combobox1` and manually change `Combobox2` or you can use data binding.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel SelectedIndexChanged works for me, but my combobox still shows all GradeLevel Colums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add filter here

```
sql = "select GradeLevelID,GradeLevel from GradeLevel where CurriculumID = '" +selected_value_cb1 +"'";
```

Comment: i can change it using my CurriculumID. but how about if i change the Curriculum Name instead? will it be the same?

Comment: you can modify the query:
sql ="select a.GradeLevelID,a.GradeLevelName from GradeLevel a inner join Curriculum b on a.CurriculumID = b.CurriculumID where b.CurriculumName  like '%" + cb.text +"%'"